# Tomcat returning HTTP 500 with one-byte responses

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, tomcat8, lift

I've been trying to track down some HTTP 500s being sent by my application. They appear as so in the `localhost_access_log.txt`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2017:16:27:46 +0000] "POST /user/174 HTTP/1.1" 500 1
```

So I added logging to my application, to catch all exceptions and responses of type 5xx. These logs are never populated. Plus, as you can see, the length of the response is one byte, which should never be the case. The web framework I am using, Lift, will return larger responses than that with a 5xx.

I am trying to catch all issues as so:

```
LiftRules.onEndServicing.append {
    case (req, Full(resp)) => {
      resp.toResponse.code.toString match {
        case internalServerError if(internalServerError.startsWith("5")) => requestLogError(req, resp.toString)
        case _ => 
      }
    }
    case _ => 
}

LiftRules.exceptionHandler.prepend {
  case (runMode, req, exception) =>
    requestLogError(req, Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(exception))
    XhtmlResponse((<html> <body>Something unexpected happened while serving the page at {req.uri}</body> </html>), S.htmlProperties.docType, List("Content-Type" -> "text/html; charset=utf-8"), Nil, 500, S.legacyIeCompatibilityMode)
}
```

So as there's nothing being logged in the `requestLog` I wonder if it's even hitting my code.

How can I enable better logging in Tomcat to see the underlying cause?

There's nothing in `catalina.out` either.

Comment: That is quite odd. Is `localhost_access_log.txt` generated by Tomcat or some sort of reverse proxy like nginx or so?

Comment: It's defined as the log file in the `org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve`, so it's Tomcat.

Comment: For some extra goodness, try giving `LiftRules.early` a function that does a `req.context.setAttribute("startedLiftProcessing", true)`. Then you should be able to add that attribute to the log as `%{startedLiftProcessing}r` or `%{startedLiftProcessing}s`, I believe. Which Tomcat version?

Comment: `Apache Tomcat/8.0.41` (no control over that - it's whatever Elastic Beanstalk picks).

Comment: Perhaps that `-` is a hint---possibly there is no request data? Still doesn't explain why Lift wouldn't log that exception though :/

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

errors of type 5xx are indications of unexpected errors on the server. Ideally, developer should put all possible try-catch blocks within the code so that these 5xx error don't happen. On the same note, try to catch all types of errors rather than looking out for specific 5xx errors within the code, else these logs would never get logged.

Comment: As per the OP, I have done that. I am similarly confused by the length of the response - one byte. A 5xx, using the framework I am using (Lift), would normally return a far larger response.